# How can I set the transaction fee when creating a transaction through Bitcoin-cli commands?

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, raw-transaction, bitcoin-cli

I want to run the following command via `bitcoin-cli`:

```
./bitcoin-cli sendfrom "10302c02147e2948cbejd9a2bd80d9691ef08a6a4d416c2bb602143a4anj06b90e" "32cjBTQkfLBp38ixj7hdjk0cc90VPPnwhQ" 3.04384215
```

(Note the account and address to above are not real, as I edited the info)

What I want to understand is, how do I add the fee to the transaction? On the [API calls list](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list), I found the command `settxfee` and amount

But where do I put this in the command? Also, the option of GUI and other wallets or sort is not an option. I have to run this via command line.

And bonus question: Where can I find out what the fee should be to clear within one block?

Answer (score 3):

`settxfee` sets the fee/kb for future API calls like `sendfrom`.  It is remains in effect as long as the program runs.

`estimatefee 1` returns the fee estimated to result in confirmation within 1 block.